# How to use square brackets in React setState?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, loops, reactjs

I am looping through fields, validating them, and want to set a validation state inside this loop if they fail the validation:

```
Object.keys(validatedFields).map(field => {
  if (validateExists(field.value) === false) {
    this.setState({ validatedFields[field].message: 'error' })
    formIsValid = false
  }
})
```

However, I get a syntax error:

```
Unexpected token:
this.setState({ validatedFields[field].message: 'error' })
                               ^
```

How can I use this sort of "dynamic" key?

Answer (score 5):

For dynamic `state` key, you can use [Computed Property](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-object-creation-356e504173a8)

Example:

```
const a = 'apple'

this.setState({
  [a]: 10 // is same as {apple: 10}
})
```

In your scenario, I'm not sure how do you want your `state` structure to look like, but if you want the `state` key to be `validatedFields[field]`, then you can do:

```
this.setState({
  [validatedFields[field]]: 'error'
})
```

If you want `message` to be nested under it, then you can write:

```
this.setState({
  [validatedFields[field]]: {
    message: 'error'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
this.setState({ this.state.validatedFields[field].message: 'error' })
```

with

```
var state = {};
state[this.state.validatedFields[field].message] = 'error';
this.setState(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:
this.setState({[this.state.validatedFields[field].message]: 'error'});
It can be done in one line, Square bracket evaluate what is inside.
refer ES6 on Computed property names: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names